# Limit $\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}\frac{\sin((n+1)x)}{\sin(nx)}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I am trying to evaluate this limit:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}\frac{\sin((n+1)x)}{\sin(nx)}$$
My thought was to split it up as follows:
$$ = \lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}\cdot\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{\sin((n+1)x)}{\sin(nx)}
$$
$$
= 0\cdot \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sin((n+1)x)}{\sin(nx)}=?$$

I am having difficulty continuing from here. Can anyone explain how this limit equals zero?

Comment: The answer definitely depends upon $x$. If $2 \pi x$ is rational, then the limit has infinitely many infinite terms due to division by zero.

Comment: For $\frac{x}{\pi}\not\in \mathbb{Z}$, one can show directly that this limit is equivalent to $$\sin(x)\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\cot(nx)}{n}$$ This equivalent limit, as far as I can tell, never exists, but I have no proof of this claim.

Comment: @BrianMoehring  If $x\over\pi$ is irrational, then we can approximate it infinitely often $|\frac{x}{\pi} - \frac{p}{q}| <\frac{1}{q^2}.$   So that $|qx - p\pi| <\frac{\pi}{q}$.  So we infinitely many values such that $1/\sin{qx} >\frac{q}{\pi}$  (maybe with a constant thrown in.)  We can probably show that $\cot(nx)$ is close to 0 and bigger than $1/\pi$ infinitely often.

Comment: Can you explain how did you come up with $$ sin(x) \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{cot(nx)}{n} $$? Which type or formula did you choose to modify it that way?

Comment: Expand $\sin(n+1)x = \sin(nx)\cos x+cos(nx)\sin x$.

Comment: Well, correct me if I am wrong but the formula is $$  sin(a+b)= sin(a)cos(b)+cos(a)sin(b)$$. So when you intergrate $$ sin(n+1)x= x[sin(n)cos(1)+cos(n)sin(1)] \Rightarrow $$
$$ xsin(n)cos(1)+ xcos(n)sin(1) $$ . Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are missing something! $x$ is *not* multiplied in. $\sin (n+1)x$ means $sin\big((n+1)x\big)$, not $\big(\sin(n+1)\big)x$.

Comment: I suspect that the question has not been faithfully reproduced. The limit doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 3):

As has been noted in the comments, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin((n+1)x)}{\sin(n x)}$ depends on $x$ and in general doesn't exist. Thus your approach to split up the limits is invalid.

However, I'm going to go out on a limb and say that you may have been trying to use the Ratio Test to determine the convergence of
$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(n x)}{n!}
$. If this is the case, you can get away with a much stronger result while doing much less work. The series is absolutely convergent since $|\sin(\theta)|\le 1$ for real $\theta$, and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}$ converges. In fact, we have
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(n x)}{n!} = \Im\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(e^{ix})^n}{n!}\right)
$$
$$
=\Im\left(e^{e^{ix}}\right)= e^{\cos(x)}\sin(\sin(x))
$$